# Yii2 Fileinput widget initializing after renderAjax

Tags: file, yii, kartik-v

I am completely lost for two days and have no clue how to fix this nonsense!

I use fileinput widget in my page like this:

```
            echo FileInput::widget([
                'name' => 'attachment_product[]',
                'id' => 'img_products',
                'options' => [
                    'multiple' => true
                ],
                'pluginOptions' => $pluginOptions,
            ]);
```

In the same page i have a button that when clicked, reloads the content with renderAjax.

On success i reload the content like this:

```
$('.content').html(data);
```

The problem is that the fileInput widget is not being initialized.. I dont know what to do and i get this error:

```
fileinput_516a5cfe is not defined
```

As i read here: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widgets/issues/229 and here: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-switchinput/issues/14. I need to reinitialize the plugin but I have no clue how to do that... I am lost..

Comment: Can you show your controller action responsible for ajax response?

Answer (score 1):

> This is by design, A JavaScript file would typically only need loading once so all subsequent requests filter out already included files.
>
> If you want to load it with every request you can add it's path to yii.reloadableScripts yii.js

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/10251